# snowflake: How to club results of multiple show statements

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 10 roles and i want to get table which contains the details for each role provided
by the below command

```
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_1;
```

this gives output

```
CREATED_ON                    | DELETED_ON | ROLE       | GRANTED_TO | GRANTEE_NAME | GRANTED_BY  
2022-09-02 06:19:36.661 -0700 |            | ROLENAME_1 | USER       | XXXXXXX      | SYSTEM_PROD 
2022-09-02 06:19:50.169 -0700 |            | ROLENAME_1 | USER       | YYYYYY       | SYSTEM_PROD 
2022-08-01 06:39:01.130 -0700 |            | ROLENAME_1 | USER       | ZZZZZZ       | SYSTEM_PROD 
2022-09-02 06:19:50.055 -0700 |            | ROLENAME_1 | USER       | LLLLLL       | SYSTEM_PROD
```

now I want to get for each role the above output but in one table

something like i run the below

```
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_1;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_2;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_3;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_4;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_5;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_6;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_7;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_8;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_9;
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE ROLENAME_10;
```

and get their output in one table.

HOw can i do this in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

You could run all these SHOW commands and the UNION the results together using RESULT_SCAN e.g.

```
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
union
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1)))
union
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)))
union
…
```

However, it would be easier to just query the GRANTS_TO_ROLES view